# Java Application runs in Eclipse but Jar fails to find serial ports

Tags: java, eclipse, rxtx

I have an application that runs in Eclipse.  It uses the RxTx code to access serial ports.  The application uses the CommPortIdentifier to set a list of ports which it adds to a JComboBox.  This all works fine in Eclipse.

```
 public void initArguments() {
    String[] args = new String[3];
    args[0] = "prot2prom.csv";
    args[1] = "COM4";
    args[2] = "Bank0";
    Scanner scan = null;
    Enumeration         portList;
    CommPortIdentifier  portId;
    String              portName;
    String              target;


        // Select The Serial Port
    target = args[1];
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        portName = portId.getName();
        portStrings.addItem(portName);
        if( portName.equals(target) ){
            portStrings.setSelectedIndex( portStrings.getItemCount() - 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

When I run that application from the Jar file, it runs without error, but stalls when it goes to use the serial port and the JComboBox is empty (except for my None Selected).   How do you debug a Jar?  Was the RxTx library somehow not included?

Comment: I would love to have an answer to accept!

Comment: Is the rxtx.jar actually on the classpath when you run your jar file? You should see some sort of exception unless you suppress these with an empty catch block.

Comment: Problem Solved.  I thought that I was done when Eclipse worked after putting the rxtxSerial.dll in the bin directory of the JDK.  The Jar did not work until I put the same file in the bin directory of the JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED - I thought that I was done when Eclipse worked after putting the rxtxSerial.dll in the bin directory of the JDK. The Jar did not work until I put the same file in the bin directory of the JRE.

Comment: Modifying the JDK is a bad style and you have to do it again and again for every JDK update.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the JAR file using the command `java -jar <myjarfile.jar>` inside a command line console you will see the console output as shown in Eclipse.

If anything goes wrong while loading RXTX you should get there error messages indicating what is missing or defect.